# Shortcut to switch between visible windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, autoit

Often, I'll have two or three different applications/windows open side-by-side in split screen mode. I'd like to know if there's a specific shortcut to switch/cycle between windows that are **visible** to the user, i.e. not minimized.

I already use shortcuts like `alt+tab`, `alt+esc` or `win+tab`, but it'd be nice if I could find a shortcut that works without opening a separate menu. Does such a shortcut exist?

EDIT: I'd also be interested to see if there any script-based solutions to make a shortcut for this kind of action.

Comment: AFAIK it only can be managed via a script. If you are interested in such a solution add the tag Autohotkey or/and AutoIt to your question.

Comment: @Relax Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you pin these applications to your taskbar and/or reorganize them so they are next to the start menu, you can use <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>1 - 9</kbd>. to start or switch to the applications that appear in that spot.

So lets say you place your browser directly next to the start button and pin it, you can then always access your browser by pressing <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

If you put your email client on spot 2, you can do the same with <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc.

If you don't have the programs pinned, it will still work, but that would mean you have to see on what slot they are prior to switching to them.

Grouped taskbar items count as the same button. Pressing that keycombo multiple times will cycle between the grouped items.

This method is limited to the first 9 programs that appear next to the start menu. If you have 9 programs pinned, unpinned programs can't be switched to using this method.

For muscle memory, pinning the programs is advised, and you gain the benefit of launching the program if its closed. So you always get that window by using that shortcut.

If the program in that slot is minimized, it will bring it back to front though.

If you really want to limit to programs that are visible, consider using the build-in virtual desktop solution. Move these windows to their own desktop, now alt-tab will only cycle between these windows as the rest is hidden on a different virtual desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Autohotke y Script:

```
; Press F1 to switch between the two last activated and not minimized windows

F1::
WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager
Loop, %id%
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGet, exStyle, exStyle, ahk_id %this_ID%
    If !(exStyle & 0x100)
        continue
    If WinActive("ahk_id" . this_ID)
         continue
    WinGet, window_state, MinMax, ahk_id %this_id%
    if (window_state = -1) ; minimized
         continue
    WinActivate, ahk_id %this_ID%
        break
}
return

; Press F2 to show a menu of all not minimized windows

F2::
Menu, windows, Add
Menu, windows, deleteAll
WinGet, id, list
Loop, %id%
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGet, exStyle, exStyle, ahk_id %this_ID%
    If !(exStyle & 0x100)
         continue
    WinGet, window_state, MinMax, ahk_id %this_id%
    if (window_state = -1) ; minimized
         continue
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
    Menu, windows, Add, %title%, ActivateWindow
    WinGet, Path, ProcessPath, ahk_id %this_ID%
    Try
    Menu, windows, Icon, %title%, %Path%
    Catch
    Menu, windows, Icon, %title%, %A_WinDir%\System32\SHELL32.dll, 3 
}
Menu, windows, Show
return

ActivateWindow:
    SetTitleMatchMode, 3
    WinActivate, %A_ThisMenuItem%
return
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue? Giving feedback and sharing knowledge help other users who are searching for similar solutions. If you need more help, feel free to ask.